# ¿Como redondear promedio calculado mediante la función AVG?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En mi tabla tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es calcular el promedio de los días transcurridos, en este caso si lo hago manual el resultado del promedio de la columna AB es de 5.666666.

Al realizar la consulta desde sql server el resultado me devuelve el numero 5, estoy usando ROUND para redondear pero no he podido conseguir mi objetivo.

¿Algo estoy haciendo mal?

```
    WITH tabla1 AS(SELECT sis, COUNT(DISTINCT tgh.id) as solalch,


ROUND(AVG(case when tgh.nombre is not null then 
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, tgh.fechacapt, tgh.fechaaten) 
                end),0) AS numdiasalch 



FROM tgh GROUP BY sis) 
SELECT sis.sis, sis.sis_descri as d, ISNULL(t1.solalch, 0) as solalch, 
ISNULL( t1.solconseguialch, 0) as solconseguialch, 
ISNULL( t1.solsinseguialch, 0) as solsinseguialch, ISNULL( t1.numdiasalch, 0) AS numdiasalch FROM sis sis LEFT JOIN tabla1 t1 on replace(replace(sis.sis_descri,'as','dfe'),'df','df DE df') = t1.sis where fecbaj is null and sis.sis between 44 and 44 group by sis.sis_descri,sis.sis,solalch,t1.solconseguialch,t1.solsinseguialch, t1.numdiasalch order by sis.sis_descri asc
```

Así es como realizo la función de promedio con ROUND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un problema del redondeo, tu caso es como este:

```
SELECT AVG(Valor)
       FROM (SELECT 1 AS Valor
             UNION
             SELECT 2) T
```

Estamos de acuerdo que el promedio debería ser `1.5` sin embargo el motor nos retorna `1`. Lo que ocurre es la función respeta el tipo de valor de entrada, en este caso un entero, por consiguiente, nos retorna `1` y no `1.5`

En tu caso, la diferencia de días siempre es un valor entero, para evitar el problema, tienes que "forzar" este valor para que sea un valor con decimales, por ejemplo:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, tgh.fechacapt, tgh.fechaaten) * 1.0
```

o incluso:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2), DATEDIFF(DAY, tgh.fechacapt, tgh.fechaaten))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me funciono muy bien y también para entender dicho proceso.! Graciass!

Answer (score 1):

como te explican se debe al tipo de datos que devuelve la función.
This function returns the count (as a signed integer value)

tienes que revisar los tipos de datos y como trabajan entre ellos (la division entre enteros devuelve enteros),
select 1/2, 5/2 ,10/5 1/2.0, 5/2.0 ,10/5.0
0   2   2   0.5 2.5 2